# llenar dinamicamente action sheet Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

Estoy buscando la manera de hacer una lista flotante(TableView dentro de AlertView) con datos de una lista de objetos y que al dar click en un elemento me entrega la referencia al objeto seleccionado.

Para esto estoy usando un action sheet y un lazo for de la siguiente manera

```
@IBAction func btnVerLista_onClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Lista de Superheroes", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        for item in arrSuperHeroes{

            let superbutton = UIAlertAction(title: (item as! SuperHeroe).nombre , style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                self.superSel = item as! SuperHeroe
                print(self.superSel.nombre)
        })
        alertController.addAction(superbutton)
        }

        self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Pero siempre tengo este error al ejecutar la última linea

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Alguien podría ayudarme con la idea del error o si existe otra manera de hacer lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La última línea del código se ve así:

```
self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Faltaría más contexto pero da la impresión que el `navigationController` efectivamente es `nil` por lo que sucede el error. Sin embargo, no es necesario usar  `navigationController` para invocar el método `present`, en este caso en particular, lo puedes hacer sobre `self`.

El código completo se vería así:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var héroes = ["Spiderman", "Superman", "Batman", "Sam Fisher", "Pikolín"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func héroesPresionado(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Héroes", message: "Selecciona un héroe", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        for héroe in self.héroes {
            sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: héroe, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
                print("Seleccionaste a: \(héroe)")
            }))
        }

        self.present(sheet, animated: true) {
        }
    }
}
```

La aplicación se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]